# Cliping a Digital Elevation Model using GDAL

Tags: python, arcgis, gdal, shapefile

So I am working on a Arcpy toolbox in Arcgis that take DEM raster file into a certain treatment.
However I need to clip those image because the original ones are way too big and too long to process.
But thing is, Arcgis clipping tool changes the data type which I cannot use then.

I started looking for codes to do that and it appears that GDAL library might help to clip a geotiff with a shapefile. Here is the code I followed with some minor changes to adapt to my 1-channel DEM: < https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html >

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdalnumeric, ogr, osr
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
gdal.UseExceptions()


# This function will convert the rasterized clipper shapefile
# to a mask for use within GDAL.
def imageToArray(i):
    """
    Converts a Python Imaging Library array to a
    gdalnumeric image.
    """
    a=gdalnumeric.fromstring(i.tostring(),'b')
    a.shape=i.im.size[1], i.im.size[0]
    return a

def arrayToImage(a):
    """
    Converts a gdalnumeric array to a
    Python Imaging Library Image.
    """
    i=Image.fromstring('L',(a.shape[1],a.shape[0]),
            (a.astype('b')).tostring())
    return i

def world2Pixel(geoMatrix, x, y):
  """
  Uses a gdal geomatrix (gdal.GetGeoTransform()) to calculate
  the pixel location of a geospatial coordinate
  """
  ulX = geoMatrix[0]
  ulY = geoMatrix[3]
  xDist = geoMatrix[1]
  yDist = geoMatrix[5]
  rtnX = geoMatrix[2]
  rtnY = geoMatrix[4]
  pixel = int((x - ulX) / xDist)
  line = int((ulY - y) / xDist)
  return (pixel, line)

#
#  EDIT: this is basically an overloaded
#  version of the gdal_array.OpenArray passing in xoff, yoff explicitly
#  so we can pass these params off to CopyDatasetInfo
#
def OpenArray( array, prototype_ds = None, xoff=0, yoff=0 ):
    ds = gdal.Open( gdalnumeric.GetArrayFilename(array) )

    if ds is not None and prototype_ds is not None:
        if type(prototype_ds).__name__ == 'str':
            prototype_ds = gdal.Open( prototype_ds )
        if prototype_ds is not None:
            gdalnumeric.CopyDatasetInfo( prototype_ds, ds, xoff=xoff, yoff=yoff )
    return ds

def histogram(a, bins=range(0,256)):
  """
  Histogram function for multi-dimensional array.
  a = array
  bins = range of numbers to match
  """
  fa = a.flat
  n = gdalnumeric.searchsorted(gdalnumeric.sort(fa), bins)
  n = gdalnumeric.concatenate([n, [len(fa)]])
  hist = n[1:]-n[:-1]
  return hist

def stretch(a):
  """
  Performs a histogram stretch on a gdalnumeric array image.
  """
  hist = histogram(a)
  im = arrayToImage(a)
  lut = []
  for b in range(0, len(hist), 256):
    # step size
    step = reduce(operator.add, hist[b:b+256]) / 255
    # create equalization lookup table
    n = 0
    for i in range(256):
      lut.append(n / step)
      n = n + hist[i+b]
  im = im.point(lut)
  return imageToArray(im)

def main( shapefile_path, raster_path ):
    # Load the source data as a gdalnumeric array
    srcArray = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(raster_path)

    # Also load as a gdal image to get geotransform
    # (world file) info
    srcImage = gdal.Open(raster_path)
    geoTrans = srcImage.GetGeoTransform()

    # Create an OGR layer from a boundary shapefile
    shapef = ogr.Open("%s.shp" % shapefile_path)
    lyr = shapef.GetLayer( os.path.split( os.path.splitext( shapefile_path )[0] )[1] )
    poly = lyr.GetNextFeature()

    # Convert the layer extent to image pixel coordinates
    minX, maxX, minY, maxY = lyr.GetExtent()
    ulX, ulY = world2Pixel(geoTrans, minX, maxY)
    lrX, lrY = world2Pixel(geoTrans, maxX, minY)

    # Calculate the pixel size of the new image
    pxWidth = int(lrX - ulX)
    pxHeight = int(lrY - ulY)

    clip = srcArray[ulY:lrY, ulX:lrX]

    #
    # EDIT: create pixel offset to pass to new image Projection info
    #
    xoffset =  ulX
    yoffset =  ulY
    print "Xoffset, Yoffset = ( %f, %f )" % ( xoffset, yoffset )

    # Create a new geomatrix for the image
    geoTrans = list(geoTrans)
    geoTrans[0] = minX
    geoTrans[3] = maxY

    # Map points to pixels for drawing the
    # boundary on a blank 8-bit,
    # black and white, mask image.
    points = []
    pixels = []
    geom = poly.GetGeometryRef()
    pts = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
    for p in range(pts.GetPointCount()):
      points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
    for p in points:
      pixels.append(world2Pixel(geoTrans, p[0], p[1]))
    rasterPoly = Image.new("L", (pxWidth, pxHeight), 1)
    rasterize = ImageDraw.Draw(rasterPoly)
    rasterize.polygon(pixels, 0)
    mask = imageToArray(rasterPoly)

    # Clip the image using the mask
    clip = gdalnumeric.choose(mask, \
        (clip, 0)).astype(gdalnumeric.uint8)

    
      clip[:,:] = stretch(clip[:,:])

    # Save new tiff
    #
    #  EDIT: instead of SaveArray, let's break all the
    #  SaveArray steps out more explicity so
    #  we can overwrite the offset of the destination
    #  raster
    #
    ### the old way using SaveArray
    #
    # gdalnumeric.SaveArray(clip, "OUTPUT.tif", format="GTiff", prototype=raster_path)
    #
    ###
    #
    gtiffDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' )
    if gtiffDriver is None:
        raise ValueError("Can't find GeoTiff Driver")
    gtiffDriver.CreateCopy( "OUTPUT.tif",
        OpenArray( clip, prototype_ds=raster_path, xoff=xoffset, yoff=yoffset )
    )

    # Save as an 8-bit jpeg for an easy, quick preview
    clip = clip.astype(gdalnumeric.uint8)
    gdalnumeric.SaveArray(clip, "OUTPUT.jpg", format="JPEG")

    gdal.ErrorReset()


if __name__ == '__main__':


    main( "shapefile", "DEM.tiff" )
```

However I got a "shape mismatch ValueError":

```
<ipython-input-22-32e4e8197a02> in main(shapefile_path, raster_path, region_shapefile_path)
    166 
    167     # Clip the image using the mask
--> 168     clip = gdalnumeric.choose(mask,         (clip, 0)).astype(gdalnumeric.uint8)
    169 
    

/home/edgar/anaconda3/envs/gis2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in choose(a, choices, out, mode)
    399 
    400     """
--> 401     return _wrapfunc(a, 'choose', choices, out=out, mode=mode)
    402 
    403 

/home/edgar/anaconda3/envs/gis2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     49 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
     50     try:
---> 51         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     52 
     53     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I tried to look around in the code where could it come from and I realized that this part is probably not working as it should:

```
minX, maxX, minY, maxY = lyr.GetExtent()
ulX, ulY = world2Pixel(geoTrans, minX, maxY)
lrX, lrY = world2Pixel(geoTrans, maxX, minY)
print("ulX, lrX, ulY, lrY : " , ulX, lrX, ulY, lrY) #image pixel coordinates of the shapefile
print(srcArray.shape)  #shape of the raster image 
clip = srcArray[ ulY:lrY, ulX:lrX] #extracting the shapefile zone from the raster image?
print(clip)
```

And returns:

```
('ulX, lrX, ulY, lrY : ', 35487, 37121, 3844, 5399)
(5041, 5041)
[]
```

Seems that those indexes are at of bounds (but strangely python doesn't bother that much) and nothing is copied.
So I tried to change a bit the code to get the "real" pixel value corresponding to the area I wish to extract by using a shapefile corresponding to my total raster image:

```
#shapefile corresponding to the whole raster image
region_shapef = ogr.Open("%s.shp" % region_shapefile_path)
region_lyr = region_shapef.GetLayer( os.path.split( os.path.splitext( region_shapefile_path )[0] )[1] )

RminX, RmaxX, RminY, RmaxY = region_lyr.GetExtent()
RulX, RulY = world2Pixel(geoTrans, RminX, RmaxY)
RlrX, RlrY = world2Pixel(geoTrans, RmaxX, RminY)

#linear regression to find the equivalent pixel values of the clipping zone
pX = float(srcArray.shape[1])/(RlrX - RulX)
X0 = -(RulX*pX)
pY = float(srcArray.shape[0])/(RlrY - RulY)
Y0 = -(RulY*pY)

idXi = int(ulX*pX+X0)
idXf = int(lrX*pX+X0)
idYi = int(ulY*pY+Y0)
idYf = int(lrY*pY+Y0)

clip = srcArray[idYi:idYf, idXi:idXf]
print(clip)
```

Returns an array that really extracted values:

```
[[169.4 171.3 173.7 ... 735.6 732.8 729.7]
 [173.3 176.4 179.9 ... 734.3 731.5 728.7]
 [177.8 182.  186.5 ... 733.1 730.3 727.5]
 ...
 [ 73.3  77.5  83.  ... 577.4 584.9 598.1]
 [ 72.8  76.5  81.5 ... 583.1 593.  606.2]
 [ 71.3  74.7  79.  ... 588.9 599.1 612.3]]
```

Though I still have that goddamn:

```
<ipython-input-1-d7714555354e> in main(shapefile_path, raster_path, region_shapefile_path)
    170 
    171     # Clip the image using the mask
--> 172     clip = gdalnumeric.choose(mask,         (clip, 0)).astype(gdalnumeric.uint8)
    173 
    174     # This image has 3 bands so we stretch each one to make them

/home/edgar/anaconda3/envs/gis2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in choose(a, choices, out, mode)
    399 
    400     """
--> 401     return _wrapfunc(a, 'choose', choices, out=out, mode=mode)
    402 
    403 

/home/edgar/anaconda3/envs/gis2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.pyc in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     49 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
     50     try:
---> 51         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     52 
     53     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Am I missing or misunderstanding something about it? I really start to lack of ideas so if someone got an idea please that would be appreciated.

Otherwise if you know another way to clip my DEM without altering it I'm fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in a much more simple way using gdal.Warp() and a shapefile as a cutline

```
from osgeo import gdal

input_raster = "path/to/yourDEM.tif" 
# or as an alternative if the input is already a gdal raster object you can use that gdal object
input_raster=gdal.Open("path/to/yourDEM.tif")
input_shape = "path/to/yourShapefile.shp" # or any other format
output_raster="path/to/outputDEM.tif" #your output raster file

ds = gdal.Warp(output_raster,
              input_raster,
              format = 'GTiff',
              cutlineDSName = input_shape, # or any other file format
              cutlineWhere="FIELD = 'whatever'" # optionally you can filter your cutline (shapefile) based on attribute values
              dstNodata = -9999) # select the no data value you like
ds=None #do other stuff with ds object, it is your cropped dataset. in this case we only close the dataset.
```